# Data manipulation using pandas dataframe

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have MxN numpy array data.
they are in csv file and I am reading using pandas module.

```
sv-01   sv-02  SV-03  state-01 state-02 state-03    val-01   val-02  val-03
7        12     8         B          B         B     .23     0.34    1.03
7        12     8         B          B         A     .35     0.10    0
7        12     8         B          A         A     1.45    0       0
7        12     8         A          A         A      0      0       0
7        12     8         A          B         B      0      1.23    3.21
```

...       ...    ...      ...         ...       ..    ..      ...    ....

For my calculation purpose I need two variable. In each row if status is A 
then corresponding satellite would not considered. So total SV in first row
is 3. Similarly 2,1,0,1 for other rows. Another variable is number of count.
If any row does not have single B ,then that row would not be counted.
last row would be considered as 2 since two B are present.

```
 #So my expected output is 
 #Total count is 4
 #and number of satellites used is 3,2,1,0,1 in each row or iteration
```

How can I iterate my data.

Thanks

Comment: Should the last row be counted as 2? Are you counting # of Bs in state columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and compare all data with `A`, sum `True`s and last subtract `B` by [`rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rsub.html):

```
a = df.filter(like='state').eq('A').sum(axis=1).rsub(3)
#same as
#a = 3 - (df.filter(like='state') == 'A').sum(axis=1)
print (a)
0    3
1    2
2    1
3    0
4    2
dtype: int64
```

Detail:

```
print (df.filter(like='state'))
  state-01 state-02 state-03
0        B        B        B
1        B        B        A
2        B        A        A
3        A        A        A
4        A        B        B

print (df.filter(like='state').eq('A'))
   state-01  state-02  state-03
0     False     False     False
1     False     False      True
2     False      True      True
3      True      True      True
4      True     False     False
```

For count all non `A` rows use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` and `sum`:

```
b = df.filter(like='state').eq('A').any(1).sum()
print (b)
4

print (df.filter(like='state').eq('A').any(1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

---

All together:

```
mask = df.filter(like='state').eq('A')
a = mask.sum(axis=1).rsub(3)
print (a)
0    3
1    2
2    1
3    0
4    2
dtype: int64

b = mask.any(1).sum()
print (b)
4
```

Comment: @ jezrael I have two doubts .1. what is 'like'. 2. And how to calculate total number of count.In this it is 4 because in 4th row there is no B.

Comment: `like` means check column nmaes for find `state`. And for compare number and then count `df.filter(like='state').eq(100).sum(1)`

Comment: I add solution for `b`

Comment: @ Jezrael. Thanks . I will go through your solution step by step

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Comment: @ Jezrael . Would you tell in short what rsub . what is reverse operator doing here

Comment: It is same `3 - (df.filter(like='state') == 'A').sum(axis=1)`. So subtract from right.  If use `sub` then it is `(df.filter(like='state') == 'A').sum(axis=1) - 3`

Comment: @ Jezrael. Coming to the same topic again. In the first  solution  ''a = df.filter(like='state').eq('A').sum(axis=1).rsub(3) '' Can I put OR condition. I have one more condition . If any satellite for state B have 0 value ,then that sat would not consider . Other thing will remain same.

Comment: @ Jezrael . For example  same data .a=7        12     8         B          B         A     .35     0    0    .  So count shall be one and sat is also 1.

Comment: So sorry, I was offline because visit of my relatives and then forget for your commnet :(